# unwanted characters in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to delete "\n" and "[" characters from jobDescription column in dataframe.
I try this code. But it s not working
`data['jobDescription'] = data['jobDescription'].str.replace(r'\n',' ', regex=True)`

you can see the df in the picture below;
[image]

how do i solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: paste the full code here please

Comment: @ImThePeak
I shared the required code. What do you need. There's also pd.read_csv, where I just loaded the df

Comment: please copy `df.head(10).to_dict()` output and paste here instead of photo

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of python regular expression.

```
import re

data.jobDescription.apply(lambda x : ''.join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]",text)))
```

The regex pattern will only allow alphabets and numbers, if you want to include symbols, you can add in the pattern to achieve that.